# Is it possible to display different login views when using Grails Spring Security plugin

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

I am working on a Grails app that has two websites: a regular "desktop" site, and a mobile site where all the presentation is done using jQuery Mobile. To distinguish these sites, I use the default Grails controllers for the regular site, and I have a custom "mobile" controller for all the mobile pages and actions. The Grails Spring Security plugin is used to handle all the authentication & authorization stuff.

So far so good. But here's my issue. On the restricted pages/actions the security plugin automagically intercepts the call (when the user is not properly authenticated) and redirects to the login page. However, I want to use 2 different pages: 1 for the regular site, and one for the mobile site. I can't figure out a good way to determine in which "context" the user is ("context" being regular or mobile).

My quick & dirty solution sofar: if a user goes to a mobile non-restricted page first, I put a marker "mobile session" in the session object. In the login controller I look for that marker and set the view to the mobile login page. Like so:

```
    def auth = {

    def config = SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig

    if (springSecurityService.isLoggedIn()) {
        redirect uri: config.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl
        return
    }

    String view = 'auth'
    if (session.mob) {
        log.debug "we're in a mobile session; reset view"
        view = 'mauth'
    }

    String postUrl = "${request.contextPath}${config.apf.filterProcessesUrl}"

    render view: view, model: [postUrl: postUrl,
                               rememberMeParameter: config.rememberMe.parameter]
}
```

This doesn't work of course, if the first page the user navigates to is a restricted page.

I hope someone can help me with this one. One "restriction" on the solution: I don't think it's a good idea to examine the user-agent to determine the context (the regular site will/must work an any device); I would prefer to determine the context based on the request being an action of the mobile controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When spring security redirects you to the auth action, it stuffs the original URI into the session.  If you can determine if a page is mobile from the URI, then you can select the view based on this.  It will be available at `session.SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST_KEY.requestURI`.